# length of longest representative "uu" in suffix automaton

Tags: directed-graphs

Trying to find the length of the longest representative of an equivalence class in suffix automaton, such that it has the form:
$\{v\in{}\Sigma|v$ is the longest representative $\wedge$ $(\exists{}u\in\Sigma*)(v=uu)\}$|. In other words how can we find the length of the longest node $v$, such that $\overset{\overset{w}\longleftarrow{}}{v}=v$, where $\overset{\overset{w}\longleftarrow{}}{v}$ is just the notation for the longest infix $u$ of $w$, i.e. $\big($ i.e. $u\in{}Inf(w)\big)$ , such that $u_{\equiv{Suff(w)}}v$ ($u$ is in one class of equivalence with $v$: $end\_pos(u)=end\_pos(v)\big)$.

I know that the charactarization of a representative, i.e. a state in the suffix automata for $w$ can be $v$, either $v$ is a prefix of the word $w$, OR there exists $a,b\in\Sigma,a\ne{}b$ such that $av,bv\in{}Inf(w)$.

Knowing that fact, I tried to prove that if there is a state with represents $Inf(w)$ of the form $uu$, it must be either created only from one letter, or it must be the whole word $w$, but I failed, because that assumption was wrong: the suffix automaton for word $ababc$ has a representative "abab". Does anyone have any ideas how to find that longest length? (Consider we have build or that we can build a suffix automaton for the word $w$ and we have the suffix states, suffix transitions and etc... but that may be a wrong direction, I don't know, because maybe we can find the answer for the task while building the SA). Help?

Comment: i.e. Does anyone know how to find the longest substring of string with the following property: it is of the form "uu", for some word u, and it is either suffix or occurs at least twice in the original string

Comment: * the length of that string